# Error while executing 'A_MC_result'

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error when running a script

> Error while executing 'A_MC_result'. Multiple values exist for variable "A_MM_email_list", however the SQL script has been written to expect only one value for this variable.  To accept multiple values for variables only "=" and "<>" can be used for comparison operators.  The query used the following operator "".

here is my script :

```
SELECT sort_name,
  id,
  pidm,
  goremal_email_address,
  goremal_status_ind,
  goremal_preferred_ind,
  goremal_emal_code
FROM donor,goremal
WHERE donor.pidm = goremal_pidm
AND upper(goremal_email_address) = upper('%'||:A_MM_email_list||'%')
AND :A_BT_submit is not null
```

I am attempting to enter multiple email addresses and return certain data.
 I tried an 'IN' clause but that did not work either.

Thoughts?

Comment: You cannot use wildcard chars in a compare. If you use patindex then you can use %  and  _.

Comment: put `like` instead of `=`

Comment: problem is with `upper(goremal_email_address) = upper('%'||:A_MM_email_list||'%')` . What goes in `:A_MM_email_list`?

Comment: The list of email addresses is what :A_MM_EMAIL_LIST is